# How to get/find an object by property value in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question about getting a list objects by "searching" their field names using LINQ. I've coded simple `Library` and `Book` classes for this:

```
class Book
{
    public string title { get; private set; }
    public string author { get; private set; }
    public DateTime indexdate { get; private set; }
    public int page { get; private set; }

    public Book(string title,string author, int page)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.page = page;
        this.indexdate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

class Library
{
    List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

    public void Add(Book book)
    {
        books.Add(book);
    }

    public Book GetBookByAuthor(string search)
    {
        // What to do over here?
    }
}
```

So I want to get `Book` instances which certain fields is equal to certain strings, like

```
if(Book[i].Author == "George R.R. Martin") return Book[i];
```

I know it's possible with simple loop codes but I want to do this with LINQ. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the reason for a public var and a private setter ?

Comment: @icbytes, the Book class is an immutable object, which is very useful in multi-threaded code.  For this example, there is no reason to modify a book object.

Comment: Where Do You know this from ?

Comment: Because this class is private by default ?

Comment: The question should be "How to get/find an object by their field content", not field name.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var myBooks = books.Where(book => book.author == "George R.R. Martin");
```

And remember to add: `using System.Linq;`

In your specific method, since you want to return only *one* book, you should write:

```
public Book GetBookByAuthor(string search)
{
    var book = books.Where(book => book.author == search).FirstOrDefault();
    // or simply:
    // var book = books.FirstOrDefault(book => book.author == search);
    return book;
}
```

The [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns an `IEnumerable<Book>`, then the [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the first book found in the enumerable or `null` if no one has been found.

Comment: The `GetBookByAuthor` method return type is `Book` not `IEnumerable<Book>` so this doesn't work until you use `FirstOrDefault` or change the method return type to `IEnumerable<Book>`.

Comment: Yes you're right, I saw that too. Now the implementation fits OP's requirement

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Like this:

```
public Book GetBookByAuthor(string search)
{
    return books.FirstOrDefault(c => c.author == search);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var books = books.Where(x => x.author == search).ToList();
```

Your Book method returns a single Book, I would suggest returning a list as there could be more than one book with that author.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using IndexOf instead of a simple equality to avoid casing problems.

```
var myBooks = books.Where(x => x.author.IndexOf("George R.R. Martin", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Or if you only one the first book found in the list, use

```
var myBook = books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.author.IndexOf("George R.R. Martin", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```