# Parsing Json data between certain curly brackets where name is equal to a certain value c#

Tags: c#, json

I am attempting to only extract specific data from a json file if a name matches a certain value. For instance I want to only extract "gender": "man" etc where name = Joe

So only pull everything within the set of {} where name = Joe and ignore the rest of the data.

```
{
    "Name": "Joe",
    "gender": "man",
    "address": "123"
},
{
    "Name": "Rack",
    "gender": "man",
    "address": "456"
}
```

I have looked at similar questions but nothing answers this directly.

```
var rootInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
        var result = //Do something here to filter data if name equals Joe
```

Comment: The text shown in the OP is not valid JSON. Please [edit] your question to show an excerpt of the data and the C# classes it's being deserialized into.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get/find an object by property value in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016144/how-to-get-find-an-object-by-property-value-in-a-list)

Comment: Parsing is very different than deserializing; both and either are very easily researched.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a list of objects under your rootObject, let’s say subObjects, which is a list of subObject.

The following code piece would give you what you want:

```
var result = rootObject.subObjects.Where(x => string.Equals(x.Name, “Joe”).Select(y => y.Gender).ToList();
```

Now you have a result, containing a list of genders where the name is equal to Joe.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is invalid. You have to fix it. Assuming that it is an array

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var jsonParsed=JArray.Parse(json);
string searchName="Joe";

string gender=jsonParsed.Where(p =>(string) p["Name"]==searchName )
                        .Select(g=> (string)g["gender"])
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```